# Use textwrap but also save original new lines in python

Tags: python, word-wrap

I have a file looking something like this:

prot17

MAGQDPRLRGEPLKHVLVIDDDVAMRHLIVEYLTIHAFKVTAVADSKQFNRVLCSETVDVVVVDLNLGREDGLEIVRSLATKSDVPIIIISGARLEEADKVIALELGATDFIAKPFGTRE

prot4711

AAGQDVRLRGEPL----VIDDDVAMRHLIVEYLTIDAFKVTAVADSKQFNRVLCSETVDVVVVDTILGFEDGLEIVDSLATKSDVPIIII

and I would like to limit every line to max 60 characters but still keeping the original new line, meaning I still want the "prot" to start a line (which I dont get when I use textwrap in python):

Someone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read whole the file and put it in a variable and split that with `\n` and concatenate the result , then split your new list with len `60` then write those in a new file :

```
f1=open('file1.txt','r').read()
conected=''.join(f1.split('\n')) 
new_split=[conected[i:i+60] for i in range(0,len(conected),60)]
with open('new.txt','w') as f :
 for line in new_split :
    f.write(line+'\n')
```

new.txt:

```
prot17MAGQDPRLRGEPLKHVLVIDDDVAMRHLIVEYLTIHAFKVTAVADSKQFNRVLC
SETVDVVVVDLNLGREDGLEIVRSLATKSDVPIIIISGARLEEADKVIALELGATDFIAK
PFGTREprot4711AAGQDVRLRGEPL----VIDDDVAMRHLIVEYLTIDAFKVTAVADS
KQFNRVLCSETVDVVVVDTILGFEDGLEIVDSLATKSDVPIIII
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to read you file line by line and then write each line by chunks of 60 characters max.

Something like :

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as fdin, open("output.txt", "w") as fdout:
    for i in fdin:
        while(len(i) > 60):
            fdout.write(i[:60] + "\n")
            i = i[60:]
        fdout.write(i)
```